# XNA HLSL UV Mapping

Tags: xna, 3d, textures, hlsl, uv-mapping

I was testing my hlsl lighting shader, I've copied it from a tutorial and it works perfectly, but all the meshes in the model needs to have texture coordinate, I guess this is because this part:

```
VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
{
    VertexShaderOutput output;

    float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
    float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
    output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);

    output.WorldPosition = worldPosition;

    output.UV = input.UV; // <--- this line

    output.Normal = mul(input.Normal, World);

    return output;
}
```

With this code I get an error: "The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. TextureCoordinate0 is missing."

I have a model with many meshes and it would be much easier change the code than map all the meshes.

So I've replaced that line with this:

```
output.UV = float2(0,0);
```

and the error disappeared, then I made this:

```
if (TextureEnabled == true)
    output.UV = input.UV;
else
    output.UV = float2(0,0);
```

Then in the game code I pass the parameter: Parameter["TextureEnabled"].SetValue(false) in all the model meshes, just for testing, but the error reappeared! How it can reappear if the shader will never reach that line? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is ``VertexShaderInput``?